# Trying to parse HTML into Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string with HTML tags in it.

I was trying to insert this with innerHTML, but that keeps the tags as plaintext.

I figured out I need to parse the actual HTML.

jQuery seems to have a method to do this, but it isn't working.

```
var article = document.createElement("div");
var title = document.createElement("div");
var articleBody = document.createElement("div");
articleBody.setAttribute("id", "article-body");
title.innerHTML = child.data.title;
articleBody = $.parseHTML(child.data.selftext_html);
article.appendChild(title);
article.appendChild(articleBody);
```

When I put this code in, nothing works.

Am I not using the parseHTML() method correctly?

EDIT (example of HTML from two different parts):

```
<!-- SC_OFF --><div class="md"><p>It&#39;s in the best interests of anyone

holding you back.</p> </div><!-- SC_ON -->
```

Comment: If its just a HTML string, you should be able to use jquery .html() or the normal inner HTML..

Comment: That's not working. It's not parsing it.

Comment: try this fiddle for an example, just made it to confirm http://jsfiddle.net/LkjccadL/

Comment: Looks like the string that you want to display contains already escaped HTML, try to use `_.unescape` method from lodash.

Comment: Can you post a demo of  innerHTML, keeping the tags as plaintext please.

Comment: You can create HTML elements using jQuery, `$('<div class="md"><p>...</p></div>').appendTo("body");`. Unless you need crazy fast code there is no need to do it manually.

Comment: I'm pulling it from another source.

Comment: Is this other source, another website? as in its not local to your website / script?

Comment: actually you want to mixup the HTML code and escaped HTML string to put as the innerHTML of some element. In that case you need to build the innerHTML appended with the escaped string (search for "escape HTML string in javascript"). The `articleBody` is the part need to be escaped while the title can be a rich HTML content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LkjccadL/1/

This uses your example string,

```
var myHTMLString = '<!-- SC_OFF --><div class="md"><p>It&#39;s in the best interests of anyone holding <b>you</b> back.</p> </div><!-- SC_ON -->';
$("#mydivthingy").html($.parseHTML(myHTMLString));
```

This works as excepted and creates the div/p. Keeps the comment tags and uses the correct quote and all.

If it stops working once you apply it to your code/variable, i would suggest doing an alert  or check your console for errors?

```
alert(child);
alert(child.data);
alert(child.data.selftext_html);
```

as suspect you might not actually be getting the html ?? possibly?

**Exactly what is creating**  child.data.selftext_html

```
// Something To Try??
// This appears to be the jQuery way of doing this... seems.. hackish?
var sHTMLResult = $('<textarea />').html(child.data.selftext_html).text();
$("#myelement").html(sHTMLResult );
```

Comment: Yep, a variant of this got it.

Comment: You said your getting this from another source, as in requesting it via ajax from another website?? If that is the case, your most likely getting a cross domain error.. press f12 to bring up your console and look for js errors?

Comment: Why would a cross domain matter if I'm obviously getting the tag information?

Comment: Yes, but if you say view the source directly in your browser, it will render. But if you try to request it with ajax... it will trigger a cross domain error as the browser for security reasons should not allow you to get data from other websites unless its a plain text file or JSONP.. If when you do an alert on "child.data.selftext_html" and it actually shows you the html in the prompt, then you should be able to simply use $("#element).html(child.data.selftext_html)

Comment: Are you able to produce a jsFiddle possibly? Does your console show any errors as this is the easiest way to debug. Also does the string contain any body or html tags? Can you give us a full example of the string, not just parts.. even if you replace senstive information

Comment: <!-- SC_OFF --><div class="md"><p> 6 weeks ago, I broke my foot wrestling and got put in a cast for 6 weeks. When I broke my foot, I thought it was a blessing because I thought a rest would be good for my body.</p> <p>Take no breaks guys. Lift hard, eat right, build that muscle, and cut that body fat. If you don&#39;t, so many other problems are going to catch up with you. It has happened to me, but the first thing I&#39;m doing when the cast comes off is hitting the gym. </p> </div><!-- SC_ON -->

Comment: The alert has NO tags, it replaces it all with encoded HTML, like this - such&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;&lt;!-- SC_ON --&gt;

Comment: It would ensure that all encoding is correct i believe, by being a plain text container.. It would force a change to the string.. To me it seems hackish but also appears to be the jQuery way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to easily create HTML:

```
var article = $('<div />');
var title   = $('<div />').html(child.data.title);
var body    = $('<div id="article-body" />').html(child.data.selftext_html);
article
    .appendTo("body")
    .append(title)
    .append(body);
```

You can also optimize the code. The `child.data.title` and `child.data.selftext_html` values look to be just text/HTML, so you should be able to just create the HTML on-the-fly. This is quite a bit more efficient, though I doubt you will notice for stuff like this.

```
$('body').append(
    '<div>' +
        '<div>' + child.data.title + '</div>' +
        '<div id="article-body">' + child.data.selftext_html + '</div>' +
    '</div>'
);
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to Javascript and already using jQuery one way or another (I'm using jQuery mobile, and it's a requirement of the project), and maximum speed is not an issue to me. I am fine with jQuery solutions.